# Table with horizontal scroll bar (No column limit, Creating table dynamically)

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I want to create a table, dynamically. There is no limitation of the input. I take input as comma separated numbers from a text box, I am sorting these numbers internally and want to print the sorted output in the webpage. As there is no limitation for the input, if the user provides more than 50 values then the output is going beyond the container of the webpage.I want to implement horizontal scroll bar for this. How I can do this???

for this I wrote the html code.

```
<table class="table table-responsive table-bordered table-hover" 
       style="border: solid; width:100%; overflow: hidden">
    <tr class="sucess">
        @foreach (int ab in ViewBag.Output)
        {
            <td>@ab</td>
        }
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: remove `overflow: hidden` and maintain a fixed width(width in pixels) to show a scroll bar

Comment: Hi Karthik, I did the same but it is not working.

Comment: Hi, I kept this table inside 'div' tag and set the css property  style="width:100% ;overflow:auto" now its working. Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and it worked for me.

```
<div style=" width:100%; overflow: auto">
     <table class="table table-responsive table-bordered table-hover" 
                  style="border: solid;">
         <tr class="sucess">
            @foreach (int ab in ViewBag.Output)
            {
              <td>@ab</td>
            }
     </tr>
   </table>
 </div>
```